# Switches Types: core switches vs top of rack switches vs end of row switches vs rack switches

Tags: switch

Note: I'm a noob in this field!
I'm searching to find out the difference between the different types of switches:

- core switches
- top of rack switches
- end of row switches
- rack switches

Are they physiscally different? or is only the position in the network that is changing? And if is only the position that is changing, where are they situated? I can find only documents with pairs of two types of switches...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since now days most of the switches are managed L2/L3, I would say it's a matter of how you utilize it and what are the needs.

Since you are new to this, flooding you with information won't help because you will still miss the basics of networking.

Don't try to compare, start by understanding each of the approaches separately  first.